# Cygcheck -c returning blanks

Tags: command-line, cygwin

When I type cygcheck -c  for some packages the results are coming up blank. For example:

```
$ cygcheck -c apt-cyg
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
<blank>              <blank>        <blank>
```

Whereas other packages return:

```
$ cygcheck -c wget
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
wget                 1.19-1         OK
```

I'm confused because I just used apt-cyg to download a package. When I tried checking ssh package it returns the same as apt-cyg yet I used to login into a vm???

What is the explanation behind this. How come some packages aren't shown but still work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-cyg` is not an official cygwin package and it is NOT installed 
as the other ones from setup.

For the list of available packages see
https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html